# Awk overwritting file's column value given as script argument

Tags: shell, awk, sed, grep

`./tool.sh -f <file> --edit <id> <column> <value>`

must be executed and for a database such as

```
#id|lastName|firstName|gender|birthday|creationDate|locationIP|browserUsed
933|Perera|Mahinda|male|1989-12-03|2010-03-17T13:32:10.447+0000|192.248.2.123|Firefox
1129|Lepland|Carmen|female|1984-02-18|2010-02-28T04:39:58.781+0000|81.25.252.111|Internet Explorer
4194|Do|Hα»^Ó ChΓ­|male|1988-10-14|2010-03-17T22:46:17.657+0000|103.10.89.118|Internet Explorer
8333|Wang|Chen|female|1980-02-02|2010-03-15T10:21:43.365+0000|1.4.16.148|Internet Explorer
8698|Liu|Chen|female|1982-05-29|2010-02-21T08:44:41.479+0000|14.103.81.196|Firefox
8853|Monteno|Albin|male|1986-04-09|2010-03-19T21:52:36.860+0000|178.209.14.40|Internet Explorer
10027|Chen|Ning|female|1982-12-08|2010-02-22T17:59:59.221+0000|1.2.9.86|Firefox
1099511628908|Chen|Wei|female|1985-08-02|2010-05-24T20:52:26.582+0000|27.98.244.108|Firefox
1099511633435|Smith|Jack|male|1981-04-19|2010-05-26T03:45:11.772+0000|50.72.193.218|Internet Explorer
1099511635042|Kiss|Gyorgy|male|1984-09-14|2010-05-16T22:57:41.808+0000|91.137.244.86|Chrome
1099511635218|Law-Yone|Eric|male|1987-01-20|2010-05-26T20:10:22.515+0000|203.81.95.235|Chrome
1099511638444|Jasani|Chris|female|1981-05-22|2010-04-29T20:50:40.375+0000|196.223.11.62|Firefox
```

and given the id column and value , change for that particular id the value in that column

ex. `./tool.sh -f people.dat --edit 933 4 female`

should overwrite the file 
`933|Mahinda|female|1989-12-03|2010-03-17T13:32:10.447+0000|192.248.2.123|Firefox`

My code is :

```
    while [ $# -gt 0 ]
    do
            case $1 in

            --edit)
                    id="$2";
                    col="$3";
                    val="$4";
            shift 3
            ;;
            -f)
                    dbfile=$2;
            shift
            esac
            shift
    done

    egrep -o '^[^#]+' ${dbfile} | awk -F '|' -v OFS='|'  -v id="${id}" -v col="${col}" -v val="${val}" '{if (($1="id") && ("col"<=8 && "col">=2)) {gsub($col,val)};{print}}'
```

So far there is no permanent change in the file and the only change there is that all the values of the first row become "id"

Comment: Not clear, could you please explain what should be your output in code tags?

Comment: "So far there is no permanent change in the file .." Many unix tools do not supply an option to overwrite existing files. The safe  idiom in `*nix` is `awk '{program}' inFile > outFile && /bin/mv outFile inFile` . Good luck.

Comment: Also, learn to use http://shellcheck.net **before** you post your code here ;-) . When you use shellcheck, you need to include a proper "she-bang" line as the first line, usually `#!/bin/bash` . Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Thanks for the tips , I'm now getting the hang of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got

```
if (($1="id") && ("col"<=8 && "col">=2)) {

       ^                   ^
       |                   | 
       |                   |
       |           Since you got string col, which will always evaluate false
       |
       |
   you are assigning field1 ($1) with string "id" which will be true always
```

If you want to apply some condition with variable then you need

```
if (($1==id) && ($col<=8 && $col>=2)) {

      ^                ^
      |                |
      |         AND column value corresponding to variable col is less
      |         than or equal to 8 and greater than or equal to 2 
      |                                     ^ 
      |                                     |
  if field1 is equal to variable id         |
      ^                                     |
      |                                     |
      |                                     |
      _____________ If both are true________|  
                      |
                      |

                   gsub($col, $val)
```

Since you got title

> Awk overwritting file's column value given as script argument

1) Instead of `gsub($col, $val)`, you may use `$col = $val`

2) and no need of `egrep -o '^[^#]+' ${dbfile} |` since you got `$1==id && $col<=8 && $col>=2` in your awk, which will take care of it, and can be simplified as below :

```
awk -F '|' -v OFS='|'  -v id="${id}" -v col="${col}" -v val="${val}" '
       $1==id && $col<=8 && $col>=2 { $col = val; print}
      ' "${dbfile}"
```

Comment: i used the `egrep-o '^[^#]+'` to ignore any comments initiated with #

Comment: But that `awk -F '|' -v OFS='|'  -v id="${id}" -v col="${col}" -v val="${val}" '
       $1==id && $col<=8 && $col>=2 { $col = val; print}
      ' "${dbfile}"` did not overwrite the file.

Comment: if you are using `gawk` use can use `gawk -i inplace `, otherwise you have to write to some temporary file and then move  like `"${dbfile}" > tmpfile && mv tmpfile "${dbfile}" `

Comment: still no need of `egrep` because awk find those line which matches

Answer (score 0):

Substitute your last line by this one

```
sed -i '/'"$id"'/s/\([^|]*\)/'"$val"'/'"$col" "$dbfile"
```

Comment: That actually did it thank you im not getting the `\([^|]*\)` part. could you care to elaborate?

Comment: Ok, I try : [^|]* mean each char wich is not a '|', so it's the content of a column because the '|' separate columns. This pattern match 7 times. I tell sed to substitute the content of the $col column with the value of $val. See info sed subtitute command "s" and flags g or number.

Comment: You must replace '/'"$id"'/ by '/^'"$id"'|/ to match $id more secure.

Comment: Thank you i get it now , and yes indeed that change was needed.